# Can javacard application detect card change on secure access module terminal?

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader, pcsc

I'm developing a Javacard application with a ACS ACR38USBSAM reader using `javax.smartcardio` API. I'm having problems with detecting presence and absence of the SAM card.

Listing the available terminals yields two `CardTerminal`s, ACS ACR38USB 0 and ACS ACR38USBSAM 0. Here I'm trying to use the ACS ACR38USBSAM 0 terminal to detect change of SAM presence.

```
CardTerminal terminal = factory.terminals().getTerminal("ACS ACR38USBSAM 0");
terminal.waitForCardPresent(0);
```

The method for detecting changes like `waitForCardPresent(0)` and `waitForCardAbsent(0)` is behaving as expected when used for normal card terminal but does not detect SAM cards correctly.

- When `waitForCardPresent(0)` is called, the method will always return `true` even if SAM is not present.
- When `waitForCardAbsent(0)` is called, the method will always wait even if the SAM has been disconnected.

I've also read the Technical Specification and Reference Manual from the [device's page](http://www.acs.com.hk/en/driver/87/acr38-sam-smart-card-reader/) but I still have very little idea whether it's supposed to be that way. I presume that this is by design, though I still don't understand the reasons behind it.

I understand in practical use the SAM would be very rarely removed or changed. This is not in itself a very crucial requirement but mostly just for convenience.